# Javascript how to loop untill you cant find the property (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Okay guys i have a hard time for this object.

```
{
    name:"asd",
    age: 17,
    workers:[
        {
            name:"asd",
            age: 17,
            workers:[
                {
                    name:"asd",
                    age: 17,
                    workers:[
                        {
                            name:"asd",
                            age: 17
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name:"asd",
            age: 17,
            workers:[
                {
                    name:"asd",
                    age: 17
                },
                {
                    name:"asd",
                    age: 17
                },
                {
                    name:"asd",
                    age: 17
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Okay my problem is that i want to loop through this object. find if it has a workers attribute and then render the values. I just cant find the way to fix this in a appropiate way.

Here is what i have now.

```
if (boss.hasOwnProperty("workers")){
    <div> {{boss.name}}
        boss.workers.map(function(w){
            if (w.hasOwnProperty("workers")){
                <div>
                {{w.name}}
                    w.workers.map(function(a){
                        <div> {{a.name}}</div>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        })
    </div>
}
```

This works but its pretty hard when i have to do with with a deeper nested structure. (on work its a 7 layered nested array which varies between 3 and 7)

What i want is 1 or 2 loops that just checks if the attribute is within the object so it continues making it untill it cant find it.

Sorry for my english it isnt the best.

Comment: Recursion? Put it in a function, then call this function for each under element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a functional component to render the current node and its workers recursively.

```js
function Worker({node}) {
  return (  
    <div>
      {node.name}
      <ul>        
        {node.workers && node.workers.map((w) => 
          <li><Worker node={w} /></li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const data = {
    name:"asd",
    age: 17,
    workers:[
        {
            name:"asd",
            age: 17,
            workers:[
                {
                    name:"asd",
                    age: 17,
                    workers:[
                        {
                            name:"asd",
                            age: 17
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name:"asd",
            age: 17,
            workers:[
                {
                    name:"asd",
                    age: 17
                },
                {
                    name:"asd",
                    age: 17
                },
                {
                    name:"asd",
                    age: 17
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}



ReactDOM.render(<Worker node={data} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a recursive function that checks if there's a worker attribute in the current node,and if there is go deeper in the worker nodes and do the same

Comment: Thanks for your answer!